# Setup Active Directory in home network - do i need to set up DNS first

Tags: home-networking

I'd like to experiment setting up a windows domain at home. I have limited resources: 1 x64 machine and 1 x32 machine.

My plan is to create a couple of virtual machines using VMware workstation, install an AD domain controller, a DNS + DHCP server on the x64 machine. Then create a Windows 7 VM in the x32 machine just to for testing.

Is this possible? (This can be difficult to achieve hardware wise because they eat lots of memory)

Do I need to set up DNS + DHCP server before I create the AD domain controller?

Answer (score 2):

No. Active directory relies on a windows AD server being the DNS server.

If you set up other servers to hand out DHCP or resolve DNS names then AD will not work properly. So go ahead and install the domain controller VM. Install the DNS services and the DHCP service. Configure the DHCP scope.

After you have done that create the other hosts and connect them to the domain.

Comment: thanks for the message. Which order do I need to do on a windows 2008 server? My understanding is DNS, DHCP, then AD, is this correct?

Comment: DNS and [Dyn-]DHCP semi go hand in hand